# length of value changes (Java)

Tags: java, hex, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am currently writing a code that uses hex values. For some reason, during the program, the hex values change from 32-bit long values to 64 bit long values. Can anyone provide insight as to why this is happening?

```
     final private long feedbackValue = 0x87654321;
     private long state;

public void initialize(long initialValue) {
    int count = 0;
    state = feedbackValue ^ initialValue;

    System.out.println("State "+count+":"+ String.format("0x%08X",state));
    while (count < 8) {
        update();

        count++;
        System.out.println("State "+count+":"+ String.format("0x%08x",state));
    }

}//end initialize method

private void update() {
    if ((state & 1) == 0) {
        state = state >>> 1;

    } else {
        state = (state >>> 1)^feedbackValue;

    }

}//end update method
```

When initialValue = 0xffffffff, here are the results:

```
    State 0:0x789ABCDE
    State 1:0x3c4d5e6f
    State 2:0xffffffff9943ec16
    State 3:0x7fffffffcca1f60b
    State 4:0xc00000006135b824
    State 5:0x60000000309adc12
    State 6:0x30000000184d6e09
    State 7:0xe7ffffff8b43f425
    State 8:0x8c00000042c4b933
```

Answer (score 0):

Place an "L" at the end of feedbackValue and initialValue variables so that it is read as a long.

Comment: What? No, that's not the problem :)